# Animation of items with WOW.js which are in the viewport

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css, wow.js

i have a list of items which are contained in viewport, that means when i load the page they all are animated all at once. but i want them to animate one after the other.

```
$(function(){
  new WOW().init();
})
```

here is my pen
https://codepen.io/kaleem78/pen/oMEeqZ

how to animate the items in the **viewport** one after the other?

Comment: i checked on github, they said there must be wow-sequence-delay like variable but  i am not sure if it is implemented.

Comment: i am talking about this https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add delay attribute to your tags:

```
<ul>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="0.5s">Item</li>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="1s">Item</li>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="1.5s">Item</li>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="2s">Item</li>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="2.5s">Item</li>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="3s">Item</li>
  <li class='wow fadeInDown' data-wow-delay="3.5s">Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there any other way, i mean where i can set a delay. without adding tags

Comment: Seems wow.js doesn't provide such setting, you may try to set the delay attribute for each element by using Javascript before initializing.

Comment: thank you for your help. i will add delay attribute.